# Capturar la ruta de un archivo en Python

Tags: python, pyqt

Tengo el siguiente codigo en Python y PyQt5. Quiero seleccionar un archivo cualquiera en el disco duro, capturar la ruta en la que se encuentra y almacenarla como variable dentro de la función, para usarla despues.

```
def BuscarXMLACT(self):
           XML = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Buscar Archivo...", "C:\\")
           print(XML)
```

El problema es que cuando envío a imprimir, obtengo los siguiente:

`('C:/Prueba.txt', 'All Files (*)')`

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No entiendo lo malo ni cual es la pregunta realmente.

Comment: El dato que me debería arrojar, es C:/Prueba.txt y no la cadena larga que se muestra arriba.

Comment: Ojo que XML es un objeto, y al hacer print(XML) lo que aparece en pantalla resulta de llamar a su metodo ` __str__` y no representa totalmente lo que el objeto es. Si quieres obtener el path de ese objeto, debes referenciar algun atributo o llamar algun método de ese objeto para poder obtenerlo. Te recomiendo referir a la documentación del metodo getOpenFileName y para que veas bien la definición del tipo que retorna.

Comment: "la cadena larga que se muestra arriba" indica que la función te ha retornado una tupla con dos elementos. El primero es el path que te interesa, y el segundo es el selector de tipos de archivo que se presentó al usuario. Es decir, lo que te interesa está en `XML[0]`

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que buscaba es el siguiente:

```
def BuscarXMLACT(self):
    XML, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Buscar Archivo...", "C:\\", "Wanted Files (*.txt)")
    print(XML)
```

La diferencia entre `XML = ...` y `XML, _ = ...` aun no la comprendo bien, pero ya funciona como quiero.

Comment: El "_" significa "aqui va una variable, pero no me interesa."

Comment: En realidad `_` no tiene significado especial para Python, es un nombre de variable válido, como podría ser `x`. Por tanto lo que estás haciendo es "desempaquetar" la tupla que te devuelve la función en dos variables. La primera contiene la información que querías. La otra no la usas. El llamar a la otra `_` es más que nada una "amabilidad" hacia quien lea tu código, pues es el convenio para nombrar a una variable que no vamos a usar más (así quien lea tu código entiende inmediatamente que ese valor no te es útil).